# react-native run-android executes for ever

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

After running

```
react-native run-android
```

Everything worked. Then I didn't change anything. And then I run the command again and got the following output in the terminal

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug)...
Exception in thread "Device List Monitor" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.checkConnection(EmulatorConsole.java:319)
        at com.android.ddmlib.EmulatorConsole.getConsole(EmulatorConsole.java:233)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.queryAvdName(DeviceMonitor.java:246)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.updateDevices(DeviceMonitor.java:218)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$400(DeviceMonitor.java:56)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListUpdateListener.deviceListUpdate(DeviceMonitor.java:658)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.processIncomingDeviceData(DeviceMonitor.java:843)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$DeviceListMonitorTask.run(DeviceMonitor.java:777)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<============-> 97% EXECUTING [6s]
> IDLE
> :app:installDebug
> IDLE
```

So the executing takes forever. It stops at 97%

I tried

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

from
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18919

and

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8868

What is wrong here?
Everything worked. So the installation should be okay. I didn't change anything. And then it didn't work.
To verify I created a new project with

```
react-native init NewProject
```

and tried

```
react-native run-android
```

but it also didn't work with the new Project.
But a few minutes ago it worked.

Where did I messed it up?
I am working on Ubuntu

npm --version 
6.9.0
node --version
v12.2.0